# Count of matching IDs with in C as query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I'm looking to add a column to display a count of all records where the drgpackid matches.

Essentially I want one line in the example provided and a count of how many records have that ID and meet the conditions of the query.

```
with C as (
      select t1.*
      from DrgPack t1 join
           DrgPack t2
           on t1.DrgID = t2.DrgID and t1.CentralMaintFieldMask <> t2.CentralMaintFieldMask
     )
select *
from rxworkflowpack
where drgpackid in (select ID from c where CentralMaintFieldMask = 0)
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server, from the screenshot. That's SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function like this:

```
with C as (
      select t1.*
      from DrgPack t1 join
           DrgPack t2
           on t1.DrgID = t2.DrgID and t1.CentralMaintFieldMask <> t2.CentralMaintFieldMask
     )
select DISTINCT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY drgpackid) AS CountRecords from rxworkflowpack
where drgpackid in (select ID from c where CentralMaintFieldMask = 0)
```

Comment: Count records column looks good but I'm still getting multiple rows for the same drgpackid

Comment: Can you add DISTINCT after SELECT?

Comment: @tdipl but you also have columns where the values change.  You cannot have both.

Comment: Then I guess I will need to exclude some Values. I guess I could take just drgpackid and count records for now. How would that look?

Comment: @tdipl See my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a thousand ways to do this, like adding another CTE with the counts and joining to it

```
with C as (
      select t1.*
      from DrgPack t1 join
           DrgPack t2
           on t1.DrgID = t2.DrgID and t1.CentralMaintFieldMask <> t2.CentralMaintFieldMask
     ),
     D as (
     select drgpackid, count(*) from rxworkflowpack group by drgpackid)
select *
from rxworkflowpack left join D on rxworkflowpack.drgpackid = d.drgpackid
where drgpackid in (select ID from c where CentralMaintFieldMask = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<` to not double count

```
  select t1.drgpackid, count(*) as cnt
  from DrgPack t1 
  join DrgPack t2
        on t1.DrgID = t2.DrgID 
       and t1.CentralMaintFieldMask < t2.CentralMaintFieldMask
  join rxworkflowpack  
        on rx.ID = t1.drgpackid  
       and rx.CentralMaintFieldMask = 0 
  group by t1.drgpackid
```